# Clarification on 'private' drawables in android.R.drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I am making a menu for an app and was pointed to [this useful resource](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/) which lists all the drawables that are part of the android 2.0 jar. the usage example given is

```
myMenuItem.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save);
```

Unfortunately, the one I want (and most of the list) are not available by default. I get

```
android.R.drawable.ic_menu_login cannot be resolved
```

when I try to set the menu item images:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Add two example menu buttons
    int groupId = 0;
    int menuItemOrder = Menu.NONE;

    int menuItemId = 1;
    String menuItemText = "Add Login Details";
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(groupId, menuItemId, menuItemOrder, menuItemText);
    menuItem.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_login )
```

Did something change in recent android releases? It seems that most of these are now 'private resources'... couldn't find much info on this but I found some advice:

> It is used to access private
>   resources. Do not use it because these
>   private resources are often
>   removed/renamed/etc. Using it would
>   most likely break your app in the
>   future.

Why would they change the resource names anyway? (The images behind them sure, but the names?) How do I access `ic_menu_login` then? Is there a better reason not to than the above?

Comment: These days, the Gradle build error message I get in a similar case is `AAPT: error: resource android:drawable/ic_close is private`. I guess the solution remains the same (copy the resource to the app).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> How do I access ic_menu_login then?

Copy it into your application. You can find all of them in your SDK installation, specifically in `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/$API/data/res/`, where `$ANDROID_HOME` is wherever you installed the SDK and `$API` is some Android level (e.g., `android-2.1`).