# How to get the private drawable to use in activity in android?

Tags: android, resources, jar, drawable

I want to use private drawable from android. for that i have downloade **androi-8.jar** which contains all the .png imgaes i want to use in my activity. i want use "btn_circle_disable_focused " drawable to the buttton but it shows me error regarding private resource. i want to use it in imageview also.

Comment: Here we can find the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636805/clarification-on-private-drawables-in-android-r-drawable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should copy desired .png to your project's /drawable folder. you can access it from xml like `@*android:drawable/btn_circle_disable_focused` but it's not a good idea cause drawable being private means it may be unavailable on some devices.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

check this [google icon design](https://www.google.com/design/icons/index.html) to download every icon you want.